# how to export exchange output into CSV format

Tags: sql-server, powershell, export-to-csv, exchange-server-2016

I wrote a `POWERSHELL`-script for displaying a distribution group based on lastlogontime but i was able to to export it into CSV-format but gives wrong results.

My code is as follows:

```
$users=Get-DistributionGroupMember  -Identity "ALL Group" | select -Expand SamAccountName   
$data=foreach($userss in $users){
Get-MailboxStatistics $userss |   sort LastLogonTime -Descending 
}
$data | Export-Csv "$home\Desktop\Folders.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and explain what's wrong. No results in CSV? Wrong results? Something else?

Comment: Are you on on-premises Exchange 2016? In that case, the parameter you are sending as user may be interpreted as `-StoreMailboxIdentity` instead of `-Identity`. According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailboxstatistics?view=exchange-ps) both these parameters use the same position.. Try naming the parameter for the user with `Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $userss`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember  -Identity "ALL Group" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName | foreach { Get-MailboxStatistics $_ | sort-object LastLogonTime -Descending }  | Export-csv "CSVpath"
```

There is no such switch of select-Object named expand.

Comment: FYI Parameters of a given cmdlet only need to have enough of it to make it distinct within that cmdlet. In this case `-Expand` is more than enough to have PowerShell know `-ExpandProperty` is what is meant here.